# Find the most common value per id

Tags: sql, sqlite

I tried this but the output is not the desired output I need. This code only gives me distinct  value for each year:

```
select distinct  (year) year, most_frequent_value from (
SELECT year, genre AS most_frequent_value, count(*) as _count
FROM Oscar
GROUP BY year, genre) a
ORDER BY year, _count DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wit `row_number()` window function:

```
select t.year, t.genre
from (
  select year, genre, 
    row_number() over (partition by year order by count(*) desc) rn
  from Oscar
  group by year, genre
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nkrtzBvw2iMaMiiVRKxZvm/0).
Results:

```
| year | genre   |
| ---- | ------- |
| 2016 | Action  |
| 2017 | Romance |
| 2018 | Fantasy |
| 2019 | Fantasy |
| 2020 | Action  |
```

If you want ties in the results use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: Just one question why do you call it t.year and t.genre.
Many thanks tho it is working

Comment: `t` is the alias of the subquery in which these columns are returned. In this case you can omit them all but it is a good practice to use them because there may be cases when you must explicitly select a column from a specific subquery especially when there are columns with same names.